# Indirect band gap semiconductor for LEDs?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Can someone please explain why Indirect band gap semiconductor can not be used for LED creation. Can you also please give me some reference link for details.

Comment: Isn't indirect-bandgap gallium phosphide used for LEDs???

Answer (score 3):

The premise of this question is wrong. Indirect bandgap semiconductors **CAN** be used for LEDs. Gallium phosphide is the most famous example.

**Other things equal, direct-bandgap materials make *better* LEDs than indirect bandgap materials.** (Why? Start with [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_and_indirect_band_gaps). If you're still confused then you can ask a new stackexchange question.) **Well, then why is gallium phosphide used in commercial green LEDs, even though it has indirect bandgap? Because "other things equal" is not the case in the real world.**

If there were a "Material X" which was *exactly like gallium phosphide in every way but with a direct bandgap instead of indirect*, then no sane company would ever make gallium phosphide LEDs. They would use Material X instead. But there is no Material X. Sure, there are materials with direct bandgaps that emit green light, but maybe they have high cost, or they're hard to grow, or they're hard to process into LEDs, or they are full of crystal defects that undermine light emission, or they occasionally explode ... etc. etc. etc.

An indirect bandgap is unfortunate when you're making an LED, but it's not the end of the world and can be outweighed by other advantages.

Comment: @ Steve Byrnes I think you can give more information on why Indirect band gap material can be used for LED and how direct bandgap material is better.

Answer (score 1):

Because they do not emit light.

And they do not emit light because:
 massless photon has (almost) zero momentum. In indirect semiconductor holes and electrons have different momenta. Thus, to recombinate and fulfill momentum conservation law they need to do something with this uncompencated momentum. While in direct gap semiconductors hole+electron pair momentum <del>is zero</del> can be zero and they are able to "just recombinate".

Read wikipedia, use google.

Comment: I'd like to add that the extra momentum can be obtained from a phonon, but clearly that is just dumping unhelpful energy to be dissipated into the material, and losses a lot of efficiency. As a rule of thumb, photon transitions are "vertical" in dispersion, and phonons are "horizontal". So by combining the two, you can get any direction you want.

Comment: @genneth, there are few ways to get this extra momentum. Phonons, impurities, interfaces. Probability is highly reduced in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Indirect bandgap semiconductors do not emit as well as do not absorb light for photon energies close to band gap due to reasons described above. Namely, the main reason is the momentum conservation law. However, it is possible to make photodetectors (absorbers) on such semiconductors utilizing interband electron transitions with energies much higher than the bandgap. In this case, such transitions occur at the center of the Brillouin zone with zero or small changes of the momentum.